# Express + Webpack error after page reload

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack

I have deployed a React app to Heroku. It works fine and all, but whenever I refresh a page that it's not the index ('/'), I keep getting an error: **Cannot GET /project/post1**.

I have no idea why this is happenning. I configured my express server to serve my static files on all routes, but its not working.

**My file structure looks something like this:**

```
-dist
   - bundle.js
   - index.html
-server.js
```

**This is my server.js file**:

```
  var express = require('express');
  var path = require('path');

  var app = express();

  var isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
  var port = isProduction ? process.env.PORT : 3000;
  var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './dist');

  app.use(express.static(publicPath));

  app.get('*', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(publicPath))
  });

  // And run the server
  app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
  });
```

**This is my webpack.prod.config file:**

```
  var webpack = require('webpack');

  module.exports = {
    entry: {
      main: './src/index.js'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/dist',
      publicPath: '/dist/',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'react-hot!babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style!css!sass'
      }]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          'NODE_ENV': '"production"'
        }
      })
    ]
  };
```

**I call my bundle.js file in the index.html like this:**

```
  <body>
      <div id="app"></div>

      <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routing happens on the client, not the server. Express doesn't know what it should do on a GET request on `/project/post1`.

So we send all requests to the client, where you have react-router running. We can do that by configuring a fallback in the `server.js` file, for example like this:

```js
import fallback from 'express-history-api-fallback';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';

// Set up express
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const root = `${__dirname}`;

// History Fallback for express
app.use(express.static(root));
app.use(fallback('index.html', { root }));

// Listen
server.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```